# How to ignore empty test files in Jest from throwing error

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am working on a project and I want to maintain its folder structure, so for each controller file, I have a `controller.test` file, but sometimes, I might have empty test files, because of some reasons, when I have such situations, Jest throws errors, since the number of files is huge it's making really hard to find test fails from lots empty test file messages.

Does Jest have any configuration to prevent throwing error messages on empty test files?

Comment: How hard is creating a file later, if you *do* want to add tests?! Have you done any research, e.g. looking at things like https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6451?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your best bet is to set those test to be skipped as [todos](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testtodoname).

An example of an empty test that passes without problem with a nice todo annotation would something like this:

```js
(logger.spec.ts)


describe('Logger', () => {
    test.todo('please pass');
});
```

The result is:

```
 PASS  e2e/logger.spec.ts
  Logger
    ✎ todo please pass
```